# Get number of visible candles to get highest value?

Tags: pine-script

How to get the highest price of visible candles to assign the value to some constant?

In this code:

```
myvar = highest(123)
```

i need to change 123 to the number of VISIBLE candles to use in my indicator.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to obtain the visible range in pine.